# Regex - At least one alphanumeric character and allow spaces

Tags: c#, regex

I want to make sure a first name field has at least one alphanumeric character and also allow spaces and dashes.

```
**VALID**

David
Billie Joe
Han-So

**INVALID**
-

Empty is also invalid
```

Comment: `^[ \-a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z0-9][ \-a-zA-Z0-9]*$`?

Comment: Don't validate names with regular expression.

Comment: @hwnd should have given reason and alternative instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To ensure the dashes and spaces happen in legitimate places, use this:

```
(?i)^[a-z]+(?:[ -]?[a-z]+)*$
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/sH9kG1).

- `(?i)` puts us in case-insensitive mode
- `^` ensures we're at the beginning of the string
- `[a-z]+` matches one or more letters
- `[ -]?[a-z]+` matches an optional single space or dash followed by letters...
- `(?:[ -]?[a-z]+)*` and this is allowed zero or more times
- `$` asserts that we have reached the end of the string

You mentioned `alphanumeric`, so in case you also want to allow digits:

```
(?i)^[a-z0-9]+(?:[ -]?[a-z0-9]+)*$
```

Comment: FYI added explanation. :)

Comment: please modify your pattern to `(?i)^[a-z0-9]+(?:[ -][a-z0-9]+)*[a-z0-9]?$` to match at least "one" "alphanumeric" :-)

Comment: @alphabravo The pattern already **did** match at least one alphanumeric character, since letters are alphanumeric. I didn't include digits in the character classes because I assumed Adam meant `alphabetical`, as suggested by his examples... But you're right that maybe he wants to include digits as well, so I added a second regex as an option. Thanks for pointing out that possibility. :)

Comment: all joking aside, you are missing my point, you need to add the last `?` to match at least "ONE"!!

Comment: @alphabravo I think I finally understood what you mean. You mean that the regex matched strings that were 2+ character long, but not single-letter strings? I have modified the expression, though not quite in the way you suggest. Good catch, thank you. :)

Comment: @alphabravo Thanks for keeping me honest. :)

Answer (score 1):

use this pattern

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z -]+$
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/rT0xT4)

oh, for alphanumeric use

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z0-9])[a-zA-Z 0-9-]+$
```

Comment: That matches `Hans---- ----`

Comment: Not worth fighting about it, but... here are [examples of what it matches](http://regex101.com/r/oC6pR9).